String Deserializes to null instead of Enum in Java Record
I'm trying to deserialize an enum from a json list. Here is my enum
public enum ContactType {
    FAX,
    EMAIL,
    SOCIAL_MEDIA,
    WEBSITE,
    ADDRESS,
    PHONE
}

I have a ContactInfo interface:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Address.class, name = "ADDRESS"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SocialMedia.class, name = "SOCIAL_MEDIA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Fax.class, name = "FAX"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Website.class, name = "WEBSITE"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Email.class, name = "EMAIL"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Phone.class, name = "PHONE")
})
public sealed interface ContactInfo permits Address, SocialMedia, Fax, Website, Email, Phone {
}

And my record:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public record SocialMedia(
        @JsonProperty("type") ContactType type,
        @JsonProperty("name") String name,
        @JsonProperty("platform") String platform,
        @JsonProperty("url") String url) implements ContactInfo {

    @JsonCreator
    public SocialMedia(
            @JsonProperty("type") ContactType type,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("platform") String platform,
            @JsonProperty("url") String url) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.platform = platform;
        this.url = url;
    }
}

I run some tests and am able to serialize an object to json, but the type disappears when I deserialize:
public class TestContactInfo {

    @Test
    public void shouldDeserializeSocialMedia() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.findAndRegisterModules();  // Ensures enum and other necessary modules are registered

        String json = "[{\"type\": \"SOCIAL_MEDIA\",\"name\": \"SFX Instagram\",\"url\": \"https://instagram.com/sfx\",\"platform\": \"Instagram\"}]";

        List<ContactInfo> contacts = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
        contacts.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSerializeSocialMedia() throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ContactInfo contactInfo = new SocialMedia(ContactType.SOCIAL_MEDIA, "sfx", "Instagram", "https://somethingsomething.com");
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(contactInfo);

        System.out.println("Serialized JSON: " + json);


    }

}

Response:
Serialized JSON: {"type":"SOCIAL_MEDIA","type":"SOCIAL_MEDIA","name":"sfx","platform":"Instagram","url":"https://somethingsomething.com"}
SocialMedia[type=null, name=SFX Instagram, platform=Instagram, url=https://instagram.com/sfx]


Why won't the enum deserialize?
